# Magento DB relationships?

Tags: mysql-config

I want to make custom tables in magento and want to set relationships between them, so I just want to know, does Magento support foreign key concept for database table relationships ?

Comment: Install Magento then look at some tables in the database. You will find foreign keys.

Comment: ok.. but after the upgrade will all my custom code exist or will be erased?

Comment: After what upgrade? If you are talking about a magento version upgrade, then your code will still be there. And tables also. There is a risk that the code may not be compatible with the new version, but for sure it will still be there.

Comment: Thanks.. hey I have checked and installed your Ultimate Module Creator. 1.Can you confirm I can build relationships between modules with that or not?  2. Is there any detailed document about this anywhere? because I am not able to download and install module after creation.

Comment: yes you can. read the documentation.

Comment: Is there any detailed document do you have because I am quite beginner to magento and I am not able to use your extension.

Comment: https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/blob/master/README.md http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/p/ultimate-module-creator.html (this is not up to date but most of the things are there)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but I guess the answer is "yes" anyway. Magento makes heavy use of foreign keys and cascades.

Comment: Heh, yep try mucking with the db and then having to restore the database. FK complaints all over the place.

Comment: Try to remove those keys :) As soon as you do, you're in the world of hurt -- tons of orphaned records all over the place in no time, aggregations giving funny results and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

As Pronto said yes.

What you might not known, Magento uses a Mysql database with the InnoDB engine, this engine supports transactions and foreign keys.